# Outgoing http connection limit removed by fiddler?

Tags: .net, http, httpwebrequest

I have a .net client app that opens a long running asynchronous http connection.

I have two servers: one in dev and the other in staging.
In the app, I can create any number of these connections.  And I am successfully able to open 
50 connections to the server.  For kicks, I tried starting 4 of these apps all opening 50 connections, and I have 200 connections open to the server in dev environment, which I can observe via netstat.

When I try to do the same against staging server, I get perhaps 1 or 2 connections at most, total - doesn't matter how many instances of my app I'm running.  Then I start up fiddler, and have it configured as system proxy.  I then run my app and I see all of them connected.  I look at netstat output and I indeed see all of the connections.

Here's a difference between the dev server and the staging server: staging server is behind a corporate proxy.  So netstat shows me that I have connection going to fiddler and a connection going to the proxy.

Here's my question.  How is fiddler letting me have 50 connections when without it, I can only get 1 or 2 connections?  Is there something I need to configure in my client code?

Thanks

Jiho

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a proxy related.  Fiddler having proxy information, were able to get out to staging but my own .net app did not use proxy and thus "hanging".
Once I configured my requests with proxy, they were able to hit the staging servers no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem. To fix it, I set `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 50;` in my application code (console app).  Note that this setting is process-wide.  Prior to this setting, I had only 2 open connections (which I believe is the default)